# Authorization in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, authorization, jax-rs

I am developing an application using javaEE / Wildfly and JAX-RS for the restful service.

I have this kind of endpoint :

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addSchool(SchoolDto schoolDto, @HeaderParam("token") String userToken) {

    List<String> actionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(
                    "create school"
                    ));
    if (authService.userHasActionList(userToken, actionsNeeded) == false ) 
    {
        return authService.returnResponse(401);
    }

    Response addSchoolServiceResponse = schoolResponse.create(schoolDto);
    return addSchoolServiceResponse;
}
```

Using the token in Header my auth service will check if the user account has, in his list of authorized actions, those that are necessary to use the checkpoint.

It's working, but I'm repeating that on each checkpoint ... I'm looking for a way to do that :

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Annotation("action 1 needed", "Action 2 needed")
public Response addSchool(SchoolDto schoolDto, @HeaderParam("token") String userToken) {        
    Response addSchoolServiceResponse = schoolResponse.create(schoolDto);
    return addSchoolServiceResponse;
}
```

an annotation where i can pass some parameters (my actions and most important be able to have the user token) who trigger using filter or whatever the security check return a 401 or let the method to be executed if user is allowed to be there.

I've find a lot of stuff (@Secured etc...) for security based on role but not on action like that

Is someone already did something like that ?

Comment: Have you actually _attempted_ to use a filter (as mentioned in posts you have come across) for your use case? If so, what problem did you run into? If not, please at least make an attempt and let us know where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes, there is a model called externalized authorization (ABAC) which does what you're looking for. It lets you express authorization as policies written in XACML.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, finaly it's working ! thanks David Brossard for the info I didn't know this kind of Authorization and I will look into it to the futur evolution of my app !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've started all over and it's working, my principal problem was to access token  in the header and working with annotations and it's ok now (just need to insist and try one more time i assume ...) here is what it's look likes :

```
@Provider
@Actions
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@EJB
AuthService authService;

@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

List<String> actionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext reqContext) throws IOException {
  Actions annotations = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Actions.class);
  String token;

  try {
      token = reqContext.getHeaders().get("token").get(0);  
      for (String annotation : annotations.value()) {
          actionsNeeded.add(annotation);
      }
        if (authService.userHasActionList(token, actionsNeeded) == false ) 
        {
            reqContext.abortWith(authService.returnResponse(401));
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Headers 'token' does not exist !");
        reqContext.abortWith(authService.returnResponse(400));
    }    

  }
}
```